# Metaprogramming with ruby, operator overloading and instance_eval

Tags: ruby, closures, metaprogramming, block, dsl

For example i've class like :

```
class QueryDSL
  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval &block
  end

  def ==(value)
    "bla bla '#{value}'"
  end

  def test(param)
    param + param
  end
end
```

and class Query like :

```
class Query
  def self.where(&block)
    QueryDSL.new(&block)
  end
end
```

I suspect when execute :

```
Query.where{test == 9}
```

the output should be :

```
"bla bla 9 bla bla 9"
```

But i've got exception like :

```
`test': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
```

Is there any mistake from my code ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're calling the `QueryDSL#test` method with no arguments when it is defined to take one argument, hence the

```
`test': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
```

error.

Either change the `test` method to not take arguments or to have a default for `param` or supply the argument in your block:

```
Query.where { test(6) == 9 }
```

That still won't call your `==` operator though, `test` doesn't return a QueryDSL instance so the `==` operator for whatever it does return will be used.

Comment: the param test is result from (== 9) where is bla bla 9.

Comment: @kav1nsky: No, `test` is called before `==` so you have `whatever_test_returns == 9` and the wrong `==` operator will get used since `test` doesn't return a QueryDSL instance.

Comment: but when i call Query.where{ test test 9 } the result is 36

Comment: `test test 9` is the same as `test(test(9))` which is `9 + 9 + 9`. `test == 9` is like `test() == 9` or `test().==(9)`

Comment: is there any explanation why method calling is test().==(9) not test(==(9)). thanks

Comment: That's just how the `==` operator does thing, that's part of the language.